# Restful web service without annotations?

Tags: java, web-services, rest, annotations, jersey

Is it possible to create a Restful webservice for an existing API without having to add annotations to POJOs (java classes)? Is it possible with jersey? or another JAX-RS implementation? The problem is that i am just having too much annotations on my classes and need to add some adapters when dealing with complex data types.

Answer (score 1):

There are certainly other approaches and libraries for publishing RESTful resources that don't rely on annotations such as [Restlet](http://www.restlet.org/) for instance. Looking at the JAX-RS specification it seems that all it defines are the annotations. If you don't use the annotations, you aren't using JAX-RS anymore.